# node webkit addon with c++ file issue vcruntime.h in window machine

Tags: c++, node-webkit

while building node web kit addon with c++ in window machine vcruntime.h file is missing error in showing, after adding vcruntime.h file from the github it shows these errors..

C:\Users\xz.nw-gyp\0.12.3\deps\v8\include\vcruntime.h(291): error C2065: '*In*' : undeclared identifier..

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7/xp:

Python - v2.7.3

Windows XP/Vista/7-Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 (Express version works well)

Windows 7/8-
Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop (Express version works well).